# Android compose dialog with custom callbacks each time the dialog is shown

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to android jetpack compose and I'm stuck with this reusable dialog date picker issue.

I'm not "Thinking In Compose"

I am using this date picker library from github

```
io.github.vanpra.compose-material-dialogs:datetime:0.9.0
```

and have declared my date picker dialog as shown here

```
@Composable
fun MyDatePicker(
    datePickerTitle: String,
    dateDialogState: MaterialDialogState,
    onDateSelected: (LocalDate) -> Unit
) {
    MaterialDialog(
        dialogState = dateDialogState,
        backgroundColor = MyColors.primaryDark,
        buttons = {
            positiveButton(text = "Ok", textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White)) {}
            negativeButton(text = "Cancel", textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.White))
        }
    ) {
        datepicker(
            colors = DatePickerDefaults.colors(
                headerBackgroundColor = MyColors.primaryTransparentDeep,
                calendarHeaderTextColor = Color.White,
                headerTextColor = Color.White,
                dateActiveBackgroundColor = MyColors.accentStartDark,
                dateActiveTextColor = Color.White,
                dateInactiveTextColor = Color.White
            ),
            initialDate = LocalDate.now(),
            title = datePickerTitle
        ) {
            onDateSelected(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I have the onDateSelected callback declared as follows:-

```
var selectedFromDate: LocalDate by remember { mutableStateOf(LocalDate.now()) }
var selectedToDate: LocalDate by remember { mutableStateOf(LocalDate.now()) }
var dateSelectionListener: (LocalDate) -> Unit = {  }
```

and when I show the date picker for either the from or to date selection I have this code

Pick From Date:-

```
            dataPickerTitle = "Select project from date"
            dateSelectionListener = {
                selectedFromDate = it
            }
            dateDialogState.show()
```

Pick To Date:-

```
                dataPickerTitle = "Select project to date"
                dateSelectionListener = {
                    selectedToDate = it
                }
                dateDialogState.show()
```

however even though the date picker dialog displays with the required title text the listener is never changed from the initial `{ }` empty function

what is the correct compose approach to set unique callbacks for each time the dialog is shown?

Answer (score 0):

you can define the two listener functions like this

```
  val dateSelectionListener1: (LocalDate) -> Unit = {
       selectedFromDate = it
  }
  val dateSelectionListener2: (LocalDate) -> Unit = {
       selectedToDate = it
  }
```

and when you invoke the `MyDatePicker` composable function you can provide `dateSelectionListener1` or `dateSelectionListener2` based on how you structured the main composable function.

```
MyDatePicker(
      datePickerTitle = "Select project from date",
       ...
       onDateSelected = dateSelectionListener1
)
```

hope this helps